# How do I correctly use the SQL Sum function with multiple variables and grouping?

Tags: sql

I am trying to write an SQL statement based on the following code.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
year INTEGER,
month INTEGER,
day INTEGER,
hoursWorked INTEGER )
```

Assuming that each employee works multiple days over each month in a 3 year period.

I need to write an sql statement that returns the total hours worked in each month, grouped by earliest year/month first.

I tried doing this, but I don't think it is correct:

```
SELECT Sum(hoursWorked) FROM mytable
ORDER BY(year,month)
GROUP BY(month);
```

I am a little confused about how to operate the sum function in conjunction with thee GROUP BY or ORDER BY function. How does one go about doing this?

Comment: Put the GROUP BY clause before the ORDER BY clause.

Comment: Don't you need to group by year too? Otherwise you will just get the month with the most hours.

Comment: ^Good point, I will fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT year, month, SUM(hoursWorked)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY year, month
ORDER BY year, month
```

This way you will have for example:

```
2014  December 30
2015  January  12
2015  February 40
```

Fields you want to group by always have be present in SELECT part of query. And vice-versa - what you put in SELECT part, need be also in GROUP BY.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT year, month, Sum(hoursWorked)as workedhours 
FROM mytable
GROUP BY year,month
ORDER BY year,month;
```

You have to `group by` year and month.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying to do. This will sum by Year/Month and Order by Year/Month.

```
Select [Year], [Month], Sum(HoursWorked) as WorkedHours
From mytable
Group By [Year], [Month]
Order by [Year], [Month]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to group by year and month, otherwise you will have the hours you worked on March 2014 and 2015 in one record :)

```
SELECT Sum(hoursWorked) as hoursWorked, year, month 
FROM mytable
GROUP BY(year, month)
ORDER BY(year,month)
;
```